# Unable to publish a service from ArcGIS Desktop to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I have an ArcGIS Online account based on my Google account, and I want to publish a service into it via ArcMap.

I first signed in into my account via Google, and then tried to share my map as a service. Yet when I came to the "Choose connection" step, I can't find my account in the list and I'm told to create a new one. I can't understand it, is it maybe an account issue?

What's going wrong?

Comment: It's not clear from your description which UI elements you have used, but it seems as if you are trying to publish to ArcGIS Server with an Online account.

Comment: It seems that you're trying to do this through the ArcMap's UI. If you're indifferent to symbology or minor configuration issues you can publish it through the ArcGIS Online UI\platform.

Comment: If you only have a public account it is not possible to publish a hosted service: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012093 I publish services to our organizational AGOL account from ArcMap.

Comment: @BERA Yes I opted for a trial version of ArcGIS online and it worked thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a public account it is not possible to publish a hosted service, see:

[FAQ: Can a user with a public account publish hosted feature services to ArcGIS Online?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012093)

> No.

Note that:

> Users with public accounts have the option to open a free 30-day trial
>   organizational account subscription if they want to publish hosted
>   services

and:

> Users can still upload data to their ArcGIS Online account using their
>   public accounts by exporting the feature classes as a shapefile and
>   zipping it using Windows Explorer. However, only 1,000 features can be
>   uploaded.